# how to schedule or automate a project build

Tags: netbeans, ant, jvm, project

I am working on a project. I need to build it on a daily basis to get the latest updates, commits by my colleagues. The build file is in XML format and every time I need to get into NetBeans and build it manually. Is there a tool already to schedule auto-builds or any other suggestions for a better way, i mean to create a schedule, having the freedom to turn on/off the auto build

Answer (score 0):

Store your source code is a repository and then setup a build server (like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)) to automatically rebuild the code every time there is a new commit. If your code is in github, you could use [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/).

Comment: Ya, what if I don't have access to such a tool. As it's being controlled by some other team member. Is there any open source tool or can I do it with Apache ant or any other way?

Comment: @ShyamSundarR Jenkins is open source and easy to setup. I run an instance on my laptop.

Comment: ya, but we already use Jenkins, we call it by the name cloudbees here. But the problemis the testing team controls the timing for the build. I thought I can have something locally in my machine. I will get all the repo updates and build my own version of a project locally and work on it

Comment: @ShyamSundarR Cloudbees is the commercially supported version of Jenkins. And what's stopping you from running your own instance and building files locally? Indeed it's one of the principles of continuous integration to continually build the code. Whether that happens centrally or locally doesn't really matter. I think you need to break away from the tyranny of a central build server. Fork the source code repo and work away. Let the test team build the merged code later.